# Android, drawPoint problem

Tags: android, canvas

if have some graphics code that looks something like this:

```
canvas.drawLine (x01,y01,x02,y02,thePaint); 

canvas.drawLine (x11,y11,x12,y12,thePaint);

canvas.drawPoint(200,200, thePaint);

canvas.drawLine (x31,y31,x32,y32,thePaint);
```

When the drawing is rendered, the first two lines and the point show up. The third line does not show up. Nothing drawn after the drawPoint shows up.

What is wrong?

Comment: Something is probably wrong with the values you must be giving.

Comment: If I move the third line above the drawPoint then it shows up along with the point. The values are good.

Comment: Hmm, Weird, Have you tried using Paths? I tried a few things, but it's behaving strange with drawLine/drawLines.

Comment: Nothing drawn after the drawPoint shows up. Not even text.

Comment: Nothing, that is, except another point.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. Seems like a bug in Android. For a workaround, try using Paths.

```
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(10, 10);
        path.lineTo(20, 20);
        path.lineTo(80, 200);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.drawPoint(100, 100, paint);

        path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(10, 100);
        path.lineTo(20, 150);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: My work around will be to just keep my drawPoint commands at the end of the display list. That may not be universal fix but it will work for my situation.